# Are height:0 and width:0 needed if applying a display:none already?

Tags: css

I'm applying a `display:none` to a class. Is adding `height:0` and `width:0` necessary?

I've seen them being used at some places, so does it solve some bug with older browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to completely hide an element you only need to apply `display:none;`. You **don't need** to set width or height to 0 as it will have no effect on your layout. The css display property is around since CSS1 and is cross-browser.

Check this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n51yLd56/)

HTML

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:red;
}

.two{
    display:none;
}
```

If, on another hand, you use the visibility property ... the element will disappear but maintain its original position.

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n51yLd56/1/)

CSS changes

```
.two{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to add `height` and `width` at all, `display:none` it is cross browser, you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

See image below for browser compatibility

[image: display:none]

see a snippet with a `display:none`

```css
div {
  background-color:blue;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div class="none">div3</div>
<div>div4</div>
```